# jQuery .each() with input elements

Tags: jquery, input, each

```
//save tablet
jQuery("#savetablet"+jTablets[i].idtablets).on('click', function()
{
    alert("alertsepy2...");
    console.log(jTablets[i].idtablets);
    jQuery("#tablet"+jTablets[i].idtablets+" .detailsrow").each(function( index ) {
        $(this).each(function( index2 ) {
            console.log($(this).html());
        });
    });
});

<div class="column0"><input type="text" value="-D"></div>
<div class="column1"><input type="text" value="D"></div>
<div class="column2"><input type="text" value="D"></div>
<div class="column3"><input type="number" value="0"></div>
<div class="column4"> <input type="number" value="0"></div>
<div class="column5"> <input type="number" value="0"></div>
<div class="column6"><input type="number" value="0"></div>
<div class="column7"><input type="number" value="0"></div>
<div class="column8"><input type="number" value="0"></div>
<div class="column9"> <input type="number" value="0"></div>
<div class="column10"> <input type="number" value=""></div>
<div id="tablet17row0" class="column11">11</div>
<div class="column0"><input type="text" value="-D"></div>
<div class="column1"><input type="text" value="D"></div>
<div class="column2"><input type="text" value="D"></div>
<div class="column3"><input type="number" value="0"></div>
<div class="column4"> <input type="number" value="0"></div>
<div class="column5"> <input type="number" value="0"></div>
<div class="column6"><input type="number" value="0"></div>
<div class="column7"><input type="number" value="0"></div>
<div class="column8"><input type="number" value="0"></div>
<div class="column9"> <input type="number" value="0"></div>
<div class="column10"> <input type="number" value=""></div>
<div id="tablet17row1" class="column11">21</div>
```

I have the above jQuery `.each()` that outputs the attached HTML to the console. In this case I want to extract the `val()` of only the input elements either of type text or type number. Is there some way to isolate just the input elements so I can get their values out into an array?

Answer (score 63, accepted):

To extract number :

```
var arrNumber = new Array();
$('input[type=number]').each(function(){
    arrNumber.push($(this).val());
})
```

To extract text:

```
var arrText= new Array();
$('input[type=text]').each(function(){
    arrText.push($(this).val());
})
```

---

## Edit : `.map` implementation

```
var arrText= $('input[type=text]').map(function(){
    return this.value;
}).get();
```

Answer (score 5):

Assume if all the input elements are inside a form u can refer the below code.

```
 // get all the inputs into an array.

    var $inputs = $('#myForm :input');

    // not sure if you wanted this, but I thought I'd add it.
    // get an associative array of just the values.
    var values = {};
    $inputs.each(function() {
        values[this.name] = $(this).val();
    });
```

Answer (score 2):

```
$.each($('input[type=number]'),function(){
  alert($(this).val());
});
```

This will alert the value of `input type number` fields

Demo is present at http://jsfiddle.net/2dJAN/33/

Answer (score 1):

You can use:

```
$(formId).serializeArray();
```